# How to set only a single keyboard layout in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, powershell

How to set only a single keyboard layout in Windows 11?
E.g. like 'en-DE' (english OS GUI, but German keyboard)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the code-snippet that works for me:

```
$language = 'en-DE'
$null = New-WinUserLanguageList $language
$list = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$wrong = $list | where {$_.LanguageTag -ne $language}
foreach($w in $wrong){$list.Remove($w)}
Set-WinUserLanguageList $list -Force -wa 0
```

You need to sign-out/in to see the result.